# What does the component-normalizer for in my lib package?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, webpack-2

I try to package my Vue components into multiple sharing libraries and write a demo based on the webpack template of vue-cli. I add a new webpack config with multiple entries like this:

```
...
  output: {
    path: config.lib.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsLibPath('[name].min.js'),
    library: '[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  externals: {
    vue: 'vue',
    vuex: 'vuex',
    axios: 'axios'
  },
...
```

The building result always includes component-normalizer.js, added by vue-loader. How to extract it?
[image]